# To set the calendar date format using datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, format

How can I change the default calendar format to 'dd/mm/yy' using datepicker? The following code is not working. What am I missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});

<div class="input-group date date-picker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calendar">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
    </span>
</div>

<script src="assets/global/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wich `datepicker` are you using?

Comment: What component you've used?

Comment: I am using the boostrap datepicker. It should be working but not. Anyway, thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [jQuery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), this will work :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
     });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

And if you are using [Bootstrap DatePicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you need this :

```js
$(".date").datepicker({
 format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type='text' class="form-control date" />
```

Comment: If I put data-date-format to the element, it works well. But if I change it in jQuery, it shows it is set to the format, but when I click the calendar, it is going back to the original format, not reflecting the change.

Comment: Would you please post your code? You can update you answer.